# Is it possible to create a array with views

Tags: java, android

I try to make something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<View> rootView = new ArrayList<View>();
```

But when i try to add view to it I just get a null pointer exception which makes me wonder if i do something wrong or if it just isn't possible to do this?

Thanks.

Code :

```
 ArrayList<View> rootView = new ArrayList<View>();
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
rootView.add(v);
```

The rootView.add(v); just makes a null pointer exception

Logcat added:

```
  03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at code94.message.TestFragment.onCreateView(TestFragment.java:113)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1011)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1374)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15517)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15517)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15517)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15517)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2313)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15517)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5228)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-19 20:49:35.543: E/AndroidRuntime(8755):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You haven't actually shown us the code where you add the Views.

Comment: Can you provide code where you add the views?

Comment: @JoakimE why not ? you can add the views in this way

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null)` is returning null

Comment: no I don't think that is the problem because if i debug the application i can see that a value is given to View v.

Comment: @JoakimE If the view is not Null, then you add it, without any doubt..

Comment: can You add where is instanciate inflater?

Comment: With the code you've posted, it is impossible to get a NullPointerException there... Could you provide the all of the LogCat errors?

Comment: Ok, is this `rootView.add(v);` line 113 in `TestFragment.java`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid, you can definitely create an `ArrayList<View>`, and you can also inflate your layout like this. So your problem is somewhere else.

You should check which object is null: `v` or `inflater`. In the first case, something is wrong maybe with your layout or with the inflation method. If the second case, your instantiation of `inflater` is wrong or missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can add views in array list

```
ArrayList<View> viewsList =new ArrayList<>();
// adding views to array list
viewsList.add(view1);
viewList.add(view2);
```

You can get views from ArrayList like below

```
viewsList.get(0);  //to get view at first position
viewsList.get(1);  //to get view at second position
```

Keep coding :)

Comment: What if you want to use a for loop to add the views:

for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.child);
rootView.add(child);
```

Comment: You ought to explain why you believe this will work, also double check your syntax [`inflate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) requires atleast two parameters.

Comment: this code dont change anything, the view child get a value, then when .add java.lang.NullPointerException